# Folium icon placement and shadow

Tags: icons, folium

I have some trouble with the placement of my pins and I can’t figure out how to delete the shadows either.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

```
for i, (route, coordinate) in enumerate(zip(encoded_routes, coordinates)):
    color = colors[i % len(colors)]  # Define color within the loop

    # Decode route
    decoded_route = polyline.decode(route)

    # Add the route to the map
    folium.PolyLine(decoded_route, color=color, weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(m)

    # Add markers for start and end locations
    start_location = decoded_route[0]
    end_location = decoded_route[-1]

    start_description = f"Start: {coordinate['description']}"
    end_description = f"End: {coordinate['description']}"

    folium.Marker(
      location=start_location,
      popup=start_description,
      icon=folium.Icon(icon='flag-chechered', prefix='fa', color='green')
    ).add_to(m)

    folium.Marker(
      location=end_location,
      popup=end_description,
      icon=folium.Icon(icon='flag-chechered', prefix='fa', color='red')
    ).add_to(m)`
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the shadows, one can use `folium.Icon(…, shadow_size=(0,0))` ([see reference](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/version-v0.14.0/modules.html#folium.features.CustomIcon)).

I have no idea how to (dynamically) offset the position of the icon, which is why you should stick to single questions on StackOverflow.  BTW, the code for your pins is missing in your question.